# conclusion about function in topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider the following topological space:

$\tau= \{U\subseteq R: 1\notin U\} \cup \{R\}$

and the following function:

$f: (R, \tau)\to (R, \tau)$

I have already proved that:

1)  if $f(1)=1$, then $f$ is continuous.

2) if $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=y$ where $y$ is not $1$ then $f$ is constant.

How can I conclude that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is constant or $f(1)=1$??

(The step that if $f$ is constant or $f(1)=1$ then $f$ is continuous is trivial, but the other way??)

I tried this:

If f is continuous, then for any $U\in \tau, f^{-1}(U)\in \tau$.

So if $1\in U\in \tau,f^{-1}(U)=\Bbb R $, so for any $x \in \Bbb R, f(x)=y$ (Y IS NOT 1) $f$ is constant. 
However, if $1\notin U\in \tau$

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have all the ingredients.  Suppose $f$ is continuous.  What can we say about $f(1)$?  (Think obvious.)

Comment: If f is continuous, then for any $U\in \tau, f^{-1}(U)\in \tau$. But I don't know how to use the images

Comment: More obvious than that.  Either $f(1) = 1$ or what?

Comment: Just so you know: English *application* doesn’t have the sense *function, map* that French *application* has; I changed it to *function* and removed the [tag:applications] tag.

Comment: If $U=${$1$}$\in \tau$, then $f^{-1}(1)\in \tau$, $f^{-1}(1)=\Bbb R$ ??

Comment: Either $f(1) = 1$, or else it doesn't.  (Yes, that obvious.)

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. What you want to show is just point 1) and 2) combined. $\quad$ 2) tells you that a continuous function is constant or $f(1)=1$. $\quad$ Point 1) tells you that if $f(1)=1$ or $f$ is constant, then $f$ is continuous. $\quad$ Do you know that each constant function is continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof approach hasn't really gone anywhere useful, I'm afraid.

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is $\tau$-to-$\tau$ continuous. If $f(1)=1,$ then we're done, so suppose not--that is, suppose that $f(1)=y$ for some $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$.

Since $y\ne 1,$ then $\{y\}\in\tau$ by definition. What can we conclude about $f^{-1}\bigl(\{y\}\bigr),$ then? What *is* $f^{-1}\bigl(\{y\}\bigr),$ given that $f(1)=y$? What then can we say about $f$?